# How to group objects with the same value into a bigger object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, javascript-objects

I have data in the following format:

```
data = [
 { group: G1, name: A},
 { group: G1, name: B},
 { group: G2, name: C},
 { group: G2, name: D}
]
```

and try to turn it into data in the format of:

```
 transformedData = [
  {group: G1, names: ['A','B']},
  {group: G2, names: ['C','D']}
]
```

I have no idea how to do it in JavaScript. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please share what code you have attempted until now. Our community members may be able to guide you to fix any issues in your code and help you achieve your desired target/objective format.

Answer (score 0):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const myTransform = arr => (
  Object.values(
    arr.reduce(
      (acc, { group, name }) => (
        (
          acc[group] ??= ({
            group,
            names: []
          })
        ).names.push(name),
        acc
      ),
      {}
    )
  )
);

/* explanation
// method to transform array
const myTransform = arr => (
  Object.values(        // extract values from the result of below operation
    arr.reduce(         // iterate over "arr" using ".reduce()"
      (acc, { group, name }) => {     // "acc" is accumulator, destructure group, name
        // set-up key-value pair in "acc" for group with "names" array as part of value
        (acc[group] ??= ({ group, names: []}));
        // push the "name" into the "names" array
        acc[group].names.push(name);
        return acc;             // return "acc"
      },
      {}
    )
  )
);
*/

const data = [
 { group: 'G1', name: 'A'},
 { group: 'G1', name: 'B'},
 { group: 'G2', name: 'C'},
 { group: 'G2', name: 'D'}
];

console.log(
  'transformed array:\n',
  myTransform(data)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Comments added to the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful withe the declaration of `data`, otherwise you would get `G1 not defined` error.

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) methods as follows:

```js
const input = [{ group: "G1", name: "A"}, { group: "G1", name: "B"}, { group: "G2", name: "C"}, { group: "G2", name: "D"}],

      output = Object.values(
          input.reduce(
              (prev, {group,name}) =>
              prev[group] ? 
              ({...prev,[group]:{group,name:[...prev[group].name,name]}}) :
              ({...prev,[group]:{group,name:[name]}}), {}
          )
      );
      
console.log( output );
```

**Alternatively ...**

```js
const input = [{ group: "G1", name: "A"}, { group: "G1", name: "B"}, { group: "G2", name: "C"}, { group: "G2", name: "D"}],

      output = input.reduce(
          (prev, {group,name}) => {
              const found = prev.find(item => item.group === group);
              if( found ) {
                  found.name.push( name );
              } else {
                  prev = [...prev, {group,name:[name]}];
              }
              return prev;
          }, []
      );
      
console.log( output );
```